# I'm having trouble with an SQL syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to add data to a table collected on a tkinter GUI. This error keeps coming up:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 489, in cmd_query
    raw_as_string=raw_as_string)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Rank,Email,Phone) VALUES(5509,'mandy123','password123','Mike','Andy','MJR','mand' at line 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
    File "C:\Users\xande\OneDrive\Desktop\School\YR 14\CCF program\CCF code.py", line 146, in addldrsubmit
    mycursor.execute(insertSQL,(LID,str(lunentry),str(lpwentry),str(lfnentry),str(lsnentry),str(lrankentry),str(lemailfullentry),lphoneentry,))
  File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 266, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 492, in cmd_query
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Rank,Email,Phone) VALUES(5509,'mandy123','password123','Mike','Andy','MJR','mand' at line 1
```

The code I'm using is:

```
import mysql.connector
if True:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="abarclay172",
        database="rbaiccf"
        )
mycursor=mydb.cursor()

LID = random.randint(1000,9999)
    lunentry = lunentrye.get()
    lpwentry = lpwentrye.get()
    lfnentry = lfnentrye.get()
    lsnentry = lsnentrye.get()
    lrankentry = addldrranke.get()
    lemailentry = lemailentrye.get()
    lemailaddressentry = addldremailaddresse.get()
    lemailfullentry = lemailentry + lemailaddressentry
    lphoneentry = "+44" + lphoneentrye.get()
insertSQL="""INSERT INTO leader(leaderID,Username,Password,Forename,Surname,Rank,Email,Phone) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
    mycursor.execute(insertSQL,(LID,str(lunentry),str(lpwentry),str(lfnentry),str(lsnentry),str(lrankentry),str(lemailfullentry),lphoneentry,))
    mydb.commit()
```

Comment: You need to share the table `leader` definition.

Comment: Why don't you print `insertSQL` before passing it to `execute`?  That way you can see what it's doing?

Comment: Fix the indentation of the code please. Use backticks (`) rank for column name and it might fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description you have provided, I guess it is the usage of RANK as a column name. It is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R). You could try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23446378/1253121) - using backticks.

But if there is something else going on, you shold provide more info, as stated in comments. Table definition, full SQL, you are trying to execute.